# Turn off Node.js Server Once Running on Localhost

Tags: node.js

This is probably a simple question but I can't find a clear answer anywhere. I am trying Hello World on node.js. I have a node.js server running on port 8000 of the localhost, turned on via the command line e.g. "node helloworld.js". Helloworld.js runs fine via localhost:8000. Now when I try turn on another server on port 8000 though I get the error "listen EADDRINUSE" because the first server is still running. So how do I turn off the first node server?

Comment: open up the terminal where node is running and press `ctrl-C`

Comment: Are you using Linux or Windows?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just kill the process by doing ctrl-c...

Comment: What if I lost the original terminal I ran it on?

Comment: @zachdyer killing the terminal would shut down the server

Answer (score 2):

If you still have the original terminal in which you run the Nodejs server, then simply press ctrl + C can kill the process.

However, if you lost the terminal, then you can open another terminal and run `taskkill /F /IM node.exe`. (/F to force the kill, /IM to specify which script you want to kill). Note that the command would kill every node server running.

Comment: Or you can hit Ctrl+Alt+Esc to open windows task manager, locate the Node.js process, and click End Task.

Answer (score 0):

If you no longer have access to your terminal, then go to your task manager on Windows or 'Force Quit' on Mac and end the 'Node.Js...' process.

This is the cleanest way to do it (if no terminal window), in my opinion.