# How to delete an existing http server?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to make a practice website with ReactJS but my old http servers are getting in the way.

Currently in Terminal whenever I type `http-server`, it says:

```
Starting up http-server, serving ./
Available on:
http://127.0.0.1:8080
http://192.168.1.8:8080
```

But I want to get rid of those because my old attempts are on it.  Meaning, it's not clearing up so that I can see my newly written code in action & move on.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense.

Comment: What do you mean by `http-server`? Is it a script that you wrote? Or an alias command?

Comment: @MartinZhai https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

Comment: @MartinZhai I need to run `sudo npm install -g http-server` then run `http-server` in order to get the server running so that I can see the changes I made in my .js file.  But the only thing I see currently is my old changes at trying to make a website with ReactJS, not the new ones.

Comment: @chompy Are you sure your code is not just cached in the browser? You shouldn't need to kill the server when you change your code.

Comment: @J.Titus Yeah, that's what I want to do.  I want to kill this server so that I can start a new one to see all the changes I've made to my .js file.  How do I kill the server?

Comment: `CTRL + C` is used to stop the server, but you should not need to do that. Try clearing your browser's cache and refreshing if you're still seeing old content.

Comment: @J.Titus Clearing the cache works perfectly!  But everytime I make a change in my .js file, it won't refresh upon hitting `CMD + r`.  I have to clear the cache every single time to see updated changes.

Comment: If you're developing in Chrome, open DevTools settings and make sure the "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)" option is checked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133898/discussion-between-chompy-and-j-titus).

Comment: @J.Titus I tried what you said but I still have to clear the cache every single time to see updated changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows you can try to kill the processes running on those ports, first get process pid with

```
netstat -ano | find "8080"
```

Then you kill it with

```
taskkill /f /pid [insert the pid here]
```

On mac or linux they are similar command

Answer (score 0):

Just kill the process by Press ctrl-c Key in terminal [Turn off Node.js Server Once Running on Localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791616/turn-off-node-js-server-once-running-on-localhost)

OR Node's naive solution

```
server.close(function() {
console.log('We closed!');
process.exit();
});
```

http://dillonbuchanan.com/programming/gracefully-shutting-down-a-nodejs-http-server/